# mongodb server error when trying to connect with angularJS $http

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angularjs

I'm writing a quick prototype using MongoDB. I'm trying to setup a quick webview using angularJS and the built in rest service from MongoDB. For viewing the website I haven't setup any artificial server I'm using the WebStorm built in server.

I'm starting MongoDB with the following parameters

```
mongod --rest
```

And I'm getting the following error in the mongod console

```
[websvr] don't know how to handle a [OPTIONS]
```

My angularJS controller:

```
var csrMap = angular.module('app', []);

csrMap.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost:28017/test/foo/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.foo = data;
   });
});
```

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="alert in foo.rows">
            {{alert.timestamp | date:'dd.MM.yy HH:mm'}}: {{alert.alertMessage}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I i parse the json data in a local file and read it from there, it works great, here is a snippet:

```
{
    "offset" : 0,
    "rows": [
        { "_id" : { "$oid" : "525ef21e89806dfa17cef146" }, "timestamp" : 1381954078346, "alertMessage" : "foo" } ,
        { "_id" : { "$oid" : "525ef21e89806dfa17cef147" }, "timestamp" : 1381954078381, "alertMessage" : "foobar" } ,
    ],

    "total_rows" : 688 ,
    "query" : {} ,
    "millis" : 25
}
```

I can also call the rest service in firefox and get the appropriate response.

I'd be grateful for any help. I've searched google up and down, but I haven't found any material on that error...

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411818/setting-up-cors-with-angular-js

Comment: Report back if it works so we can make an answer out of your question :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the error message on the server side any more, but I obviously do get an error response. Because if I do this: `$http.get('http://localhost:28017/test/foo/').error(function(data) {
        $scope.foo = "error";
   });` I can printout foo

Comment: I've done some more trial and error, temper data says I get a response from the server with http status 200, but in angularJS I'm getting an error response with the http status 0 (???) tried by `$http.get('http://localhost:28017/test/foo/').error(function(data, status) {
      alert(status);
   })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is:

Use a REST Service instead of an http Service (which the Simple Rest Service from MongoDB obviously is) and everything works fine. I'm using kule now and everything works as intended.
I found the answer here: [Using AngularJs and MongoDB/Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881161/using-angularjs-and-mongodb-mongoose)

Find the REST Services for MongoDB here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#HttpInterface-RESTInterfaces