# Can't perform CORS request using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am writing my first AngularJS app and have run into a problem with CORS in Angular. Have tried what was mentioned in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411818/setting-up-cors-with-angular-js) but still have no luck solving this.

The JS code (main.js) is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var postData = "username=demo&password=demo";
    $http.post("http://sampleurl.com/login",postData).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

The Index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Angular App</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have tried running this request using Ajax and it works just fine with Ajax. For some reason can't get this to work using Angular. Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So basically after alot of tinkering around I realised that params were not getting passed using

```
  $http.post("http://sampleurl.com/login",postData)
```

So I rewrote this request as follows:

```
 $http({
    url:'http://sampleurl.com/api',
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: postData
  })
```

This got the request to go through just fine. Hope this is of help to someone else.

Cheers!

Comment: Man, you made my day so much! I was struggling badly with this issue!!! Thanks, thanks! (PS: the are some "angles" from Angular that I don't like much :-D )

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you will need to do, in the .config you need to put this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

And then on your server you need to return an an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, it would possibly look like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://URL_OF_SITE_YOUR_ANGULARJS_APP_IS_AT
```

Comment: Hey @Matthew, Thanks for this. I added the .withCredentials line and at least the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error has gone. After running the code again I see an OPTIONS return in console which is weird as the request is a POST. I examined the request, and the Origin is set to NULL. On the server side, have programmed   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",

Comment: That's how CORS works, there will be an options request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a CORS request '**withCredentials**', you'll need to have your server reply with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'**http(s)://your.request.origin**'. A wildcard (*) reply will be **refused** by most browsers **for requests with credentials**.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue, then I read from this link:
http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

and things worked like a charm :)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myAppApiService']);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and I resolve it by adding this header:

```
headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
```