# angular 2 npm start - how to proxy API requests to another server?

Tags: angular, npm

How can I proxy my AJAX calls to a different server using npm start. 
npm start --proxy http://localhost:8080 doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it ... One option is to add file:

`bs-config.js`:

```
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = {
    server: {
        middleware: {
            1: proxyMiddleware('/api', {
                target: 'http://localhost:8081/',
                changeOrigin: true
            })
        }
    }
};
```

Also run: `npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware`

Comment: Where to add this file? at the root folder?

Comment: Not working for me...Please explain more...like where to put this file..I have placed in root directory of project (outside src) and then npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware. Then when I did npm run start, it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

proxy option for npm is to configure npm behind the proxy. If you need to proxy localhost calls to other server try using http-proxy package: https://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro/

You can also add more details to your question. For example, what you are trying to achieve and your network configuration. There maybe other more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank for your time.
The thing is that I'm new in angular 2 and I'm playing with a official tutorial. I came to http and I created simple spring based rest api.
The problem is when I start my web app using [ npm start ] I can't invoke rest endpoint because of CORS. I wander if I could do a proxy without using grunt, gulp or what ever ... just using [ npm start ] with some magic parameter

Comment: In most cases when you run frontend locally and invoke some api, the api server also runs locally. If it is not your case try that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019669/cant-perform-cors-request-using-angularjs